# Binary relations as the topological closure of the diagonal

Tags: gn.general-topology

If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, we can consider the product topology on $X\times X$ and take the closure of the diagonal $\Delta_X = \{(x,x): x\in X\}$, which we denote by $\mathrm{cl}(\Delta_X)$. Obviously, $\mathrm{cl}(\Delta_X)$ is a symmetric binary relation.

Now we can take things upside down: Let $X$ be a set and let $R\subseteq X\times X$ be a reflexive and symmetric relation. Is there a topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $\mathrm{cl}(\Delta_X)=R$?

Comment: That's right - I just edited my post accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Consider at least 4-point set $X$, and an involution $\ i:X\rightarrow X\ $ without any fixed point (i.e. $\ (i\circ i)(x)=x\ne i(x)\ $ for every $\ x\in X).\ $ Let $\ R:= \{(x\ y)\in X\times x: y\ne x \}.\ $ Then on one hand $X$ would be discrete, while on the other hand $R$ is different from the diagonal $\ \{(x\ x):x\in X\}.$

Comment: I said *discrete* but it can be anything because the would be space would not be a topological space.

Comment: Just for non-general-topologists, Bourbaki has proved that a topological space $\ X\ $ is Hausdorff $\ \Leftrightarrow\ $ the diagonal of $\ X\times X\ $ is closed. Thus indeed for each fixed point free involution in any at least 4-point space we gat a counterexample.

Comment: Consider at least 4-point set $X$, and an involution  $\ i:X\rightarrow X\ $  without any fixed point (i.e.  $\ (i\circ i)(x)=x\ne i(x)\ $  for every  $\ x\in X).\ $ Let  $\ R\ :=\ \{(x y)\in X\times X:y\ne i(x)\}.\ $  Then on one hand $\ X\ $ would be discrete, while on the other hand $\ R\ $ is different from the diagonal $ \{(x x):x\in X\}$.

Comment: I was fighting typos. It's hard!!! :-) This matter seemed too simple for a whole *ANSWER* but when I try to correct typos in a comment then the original text of the comment vanishes during the editing, and I am lost :-)

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski I suggest that you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Joel, I decided to follow your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no, not necessarily. For a counterexample, let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and let $aRb\iff a=b \text{ or } |a-b|\geq 1$, the "equal or differ by at least one" relation. This is symmetric and reflexive. Suppose $\tau$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\text{cl}(\Delta)=R$. For any real number $k$, the $k^{\rm th}$ slice in the plane leads to $(k-1,k)\cup(k,k+1)$ being open with respect to $\tau$. By taking intersections of such sets, we get tiny open intervals $(a,b)$ being open, and this violates $\text{cl}(\Delta)=R$.

Comment: Thanks! - Is it also possible to find an **equivalence** relation $R$ on a set $X$ such that there is no topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $\mathrm{cl}(\Delta_X) = R$?

Comment: Sorry, I’m missing something. How can you get a tiny interval by taking unions of unbounded sets?

Comment: No, I believe every equivalence relation will be the closure of the diagonal, if you take the discrete topology on the classes, with the indiscrete topology inside each class. The relation $R$ looks like a diagonal bunch of squares.

Comment: Emil, oops, I have confused two versions of examples I was looking at. I edited with a different argument--does it work now?

Comment: Hi @dominiczypen!,  I didn´t know you were on MO! I just mentioned you in my answer, what are the odds?

Comment: I guess I am being dense today, but how does this violate $\mathrm{cl}(\Delta)=R$? The sets you constructed have fip, hence they cannot separate any points by themselves.

Comment: OK, it is fixed now; sorry for the false start.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\ |X|\ge 4,\ $ e.g. $\ X := \mathbb Z/4.\ $ Let $\ j : X\rightarrow X\ $ be an involution without any fixed point, i.e. $\ (j\circ j)(x) = x \ne j(x)\ $ for every $\ x\in X;\ $ e.g. $\ j(x) = x+2 \mod 4\ $. Let

$$ R\ :=\ \{ (x\ y)\in X^2\ :\ y\ne j(x) \} $$

Then there does not exist a topology $\ T\ $ in $\ X\ $ such that $\ R\ $ is the closure of the diagonal $\ D := \{ (x\ x):\ x\in X\}\ \subseteq X^2$.

---

**PROOF**   By a contradiction, let $\ T\ $ be a topology in $\ X\ $ as described above. The functions $\ I_X : X\rightarrow X\ $ and $\ \imath_x : \{x\} \rightarrow X\ $ such $\ I(t):=t\ $ for every $\ t\in X\ $ and $\ \imath_x(x):=x\ $ are continuous. Thus the diagonal product $\ I_X\Delta\imath_x : X\rightarrow X^2\ $ is continuous; and so is the projection $\ \pi_1:X^2\rightarrow X\ $ given by $\ \pi_1(t\ u) := t.\ $ It follows that the canonical bijection

$$\ b_x := \pi_1|X\times\{x\} :\ X\times \{x\} \rightarrow X$$

is a homeomorphism. Thus $\ X\setminus\{\imath(y)\} = \pi_1(R\ \cap\ X\times \{y\}\ $ is closed in $\ X\ $ for each $\ y\in X,\ $ hence $\ \{x\}\ $ is open in $\ X\ $ for $\ y:=j(x);\ $ this means that $\ \{x\} $ is open for every $\ x\in X,\ $ i.e. $\ X\ $ would be Hausdorff. However the closure $\ R\ $ of the diagonal is different from the diagonal--a contradiction. (*so much for an intro to Gen. Top.; sorry to be boring*).

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.3877v1.pdf) article of Colasante and Van Der Zypen, it is an open problem to characterize those reflexive and symmetric relations for which there is such a topology. If we restrict ourselves to $T_2$ topologies then we all know that only the identity relation admitts one. In the paper I just mentioned, Colasnate and Van Der Zypen show that an **equivalence** relation on an infinite $X$ admits a $T_1$ topology if and only if it has infinitely many equivalence classes or every finite equivalence class is a singleton.